# VM running across multiple hardware

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualization

Is it possible to deploy a single Virtual Machine instance to run across multiple physical hardware using Ubuntu's virtualization solution, namely KVM, MAAS, JUJU, etc?

Imagine the following scenario, a virtual infrastructure with two physical servers of two core processors and 4 GB Memory each. Can I define a virtual machine use up to 3 core processors and 6 GB Memory to run on this virtual infrastructure?

If this is possible, will it have any impact in terms of performance or is there any additional requirements on the hardware, eg. Fibre channels between servers in order to avoid performance degradation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible/impractical for a variety of reasons. The problem is usually solved at the application level, where an application (database etc.) can transparently scale across multiple machines, achieving the same effect as if it was running on a faster machine with more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that, but the below might provide you some new insights :
[Scalemp](http://www.scalemp.com/Datasheets/vSMP_Foundation_Solutions_Datasheet.pdf)